# Retrieve specific text freebase/WEX python re

Tags: python, regex, tags, freebase

let's say I have text/string like this

```
This is something before any tag, today's date is 09-06-2012 blah blah
<firsttag> content of first tag </firsttag> <sentence> This is the
first sentence in my paragraph that needs to be <bold> displayed.
</bold> </sentence> <secondtag> blah blah blah <italics> another blah
</italics></secondtag> <sentence> This is the second sentence in my
paragraph that needs to be displayed and it has some weird contents
like \n\n\n and inbetween reference tags like <link> http://google.com
</link></sentence> <thirdtag>blah blah </thirdtag><sentence>Tennis is
a great sport, I'm really sad that <link
synthetic="True"><target>Roger Federer </link></target>Roger Federer
lost yesterday.</sentence>
```

Output should be like this

> This is the first sentence in my paragraph that needs to be
>   displayed.This is the second sentence in my paragraph that needs to be
>   displayed and it has some weird contents like and inbetween reference
>   tags likeTennis is a great sport, I'm really sad that Roger Federer
>   lost yesterday.

My output after regex parsing should only we the content inside  and  tags. All tags, weird \n\n characters, all junk content inside  needs to be removed, like in the case of "Roger Federer" as the link just merely points to a page of Roger Federer as this is a Freebase-wiki (WEX) dataset that I'm dealing with. A simple python re code to help me solve this problem would be extremely useful. The code that I'm trying is like this.

```
for line in fileinput.input():
        p = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', line)
        p = re.sub('\n','',p)
print p
```

Since I'm dealing with huge files, if you can help me with a map-reduce (hadoop) code it would also be very helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered a custom solution for your problem. You have to input your string as the parameter `s`.

```
def convert_with_regex(s):
    sents = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>", re.S)
    fin = re.compile(r"<(.*)>(.*?)</.*>|[\n]+", re.S)
    result=[]
    for sent in sents.findall(s.replace("<bold>","").replace("</bold>","")):
        result.append(fin.sub("",sent))
    return ''.join(result)
```

I know it's not that elegant but "Form follows function" :)